# NAudio playback sample values much smaller than recorded values

Tags: c#, naudio, waveout

When I record with nAudio using waveIn the buffer values that I get are large, my chart needs to be scaled to around 20 000 to display the samples correctly. When I replay this audio from the recorded wave file and capture samples from the waveOut using a SampleChannel sample provider the values are tiny.

The file format says the values it is giving me have a blockAlign of 8 with 32 bits per sample (float?) and 2 channels. Does this mean that 2x4 floats should be combined in some way to create each channels value?

I notice the floats in the supplied buffer arrays are discrete, they are multiples of 3.05175781E-05 in float format.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do here. Do I need to process the floats that a waveout sampleProvider creates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `waveIn`, you're likely recording 16 bit samples, so they are `short` or `Int16` values in the range -32768 to 32767

When you deal with floating point (`float` or `Single`) samples, they are normalised into the range -1.0 to 1.0.

Comment: OK makes sense, was thinking this might have been the answer last night, so to match the waveout I'll normalize my wavein values as well by dividing them by 32768, Thanks heaps, naudio has been great for the project I've been given and the videos on pluralsight where very helpful

Comment: the reason the WaveOut sample values are not in the same range is that samplechannel is turning them into floating point